# jquery class selector does not work

Tags: jquery, class

I have an input field to which I add a class when it gets the focus. If it loses the focus, the class should be removed and another class added.

```
<input type="text" class="input" />

$(document).ready(function () {

        $(".input").focus(function () {
            $(this).addClass("focus");
        });

        $(".input.focus").blur(function () {
            $(this).removeClass("focus").addClass("error");
        });
});

.input.error
{           
    border: 2px solid Red;         
}

.input.focus
{           
    border: 2px solid Yellow;       
}
```

Adding the class works fine, but not the blur function. What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try...

```
$(".input").focus(..).blur(..);
```

when the $(document).ready is fired, there is no element with both classes..

Answer (score 2):

When you bind the `blur` handler, your selector (`$(".input.focus")`) doesn't return any elements.

You need to bind a dynamic handler that works for current and future elements:

```
$('body').on('blur', '.input.focus', function () {
  $(this).removeClass("focus").addClass("error");
});
```

For speed improvements, replace `body` with the parent container of these elements.

Although this is a bit overkill for focus and blur. You can try something like this:

```
$('.input').on('focus', function() {
  $(this).removeClass('error').addClass('focus');
}).on('blur', function() {
  $(this).removeClass('focus').addClass('error');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you're binding the blur event to an element that doesn't exist yet.

When you do `$(document).ready` it runs when the document first loads, so it'll go and find an element `.input.focus` - however there is no element with that class yet.

You need to add this code after the element is created, or by using jQuery live

Change your code to the below for usage with jQuery live. JsFiddle demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/RDEXg/

```
<input type="text" class="input" />

$(document).ready(function () {

        $(".input").focus(function () {
            $(this).addClass("focus");
        });

        $(".input.focus").live('blur',function () {
            $(this).removeClass("focus").addClass("error");
        });
});

.input.error
{           
    border: 2px solid Red;         
}

.input.focus
{           
    border: 2px solid Yellow;       
}
```

You need the .live('blur',... option as you're adding this event listener on document ready. .input.focus does not exist on document ready. More reading here: http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use .delegate() in preference to .live().